# Add parent ID to big css file

Tags: css, regex, class, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a parent ID to each css item in Twitter Bootstrap. I've found the RegEx tool, but I haven't found the right code combination.

I have to do this because I can only target an area within the site I'm working on.

Essentially, I want to go from this:

```
.offset1{margin-left:100px;}
.row-fluid{width:100%;*zoom:1;} .row-fluid:before, .row-fluid:after{display:table;content:"";line-height:0;}
```

To this:

```
#parent .offset1{margin-left:100px;}
#parent .row-fluid{width:100%;*zoom:1;} #parent .row-fluid:before {display:table;content:"";line-height:0;}
```

Can anyone help?

thanks, Ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap is written with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), so you should be able to utilize it's nesting rules for this:

```
#parent {
    /*everything in the less file */
}
```

There are a couple of .less files to do this to, but I think it's still a pretty easy option. Note that I haven't tried this myself, but it **should** work. :)

Obviously you'd have to download the LESS source and recompile it to CSS. It can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/

Constructing a regex for doing this to every CSS selector in Bootstrap seems like a pretty daunting task. You could potentially cause errors you won't notice until much later.

Comment: Hi Anders - yes, I was worried about the regex doing that.

I should have explained further - I'm unable to add any js to the site, so yes, LESS would have been the answer - boo.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: - Edit: I can add an external js file - so I can less it up - yay!

Comment: Anders - any idea where the less.js file is in the github version?

Comment: As far as I know bootstrap is "compiled" into normal CSS before used, and not used with less.js on the fly. The bootstrap guys compile it using node.